# Using TeamCity with MSBuild and Build Parameters (not beeing used)

Tags: build, msbuild, teamcity, build-automation

I've had command line params for my projects configured in teamcity and got tired on the warning in build logs:

```
MSBuild command line parameters contain "/property:" or "/p:". It is recommended to define System Property on Build Parameters instead.
```

Now I've tried to move from the manually entered properties all arround my projects into `Build  Parameters` and a template. But no matter what I try, it's telling me nothing about what I've set up for configuration there and is not even using it at all.

How would one properly map something like `/p:Configuration=StagingDeploy` to a build parameter, and of what type should it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry to answer my own question, nevertheless, maybe this helps someone to get this right earlier then me.

It seems you have to define `System Properties` instead of `Configuration Parameters` under the `Build Parameters` tab in TeamCity. I'm a little confused why they've used this naming, but as the warning already stated:

```
It is recommended to define System Property on Build Parameters instead.
```

You're clearly in advance if you're able to read here.

Sorry.

Comment: Same issue here, but one question, what is the system property value? Is it `/p:Configuration=StagingDeploy` or `StagingDeploy`, I've tried the first one and the message is still generated.

Comment: @Samuel Inside for creating parameters, you have to switch the type to System Property and then enter StatgingDeploy and the value you wanted. I could update my answer with screenshots when I'm at work tomorrow...

Comment: Did you solve the issue that `StagingDeploy` is sent to each msbuild step? Do you have build configs building multiple configurations? If the system property is sent to each build step, it gets quite tricky to have one step building debug, one release, etc.

Comment: Sooo, why don't you go by "don't move that parameter into the Configuration Parameters section"? I mean it's not something that is the same for all build steps. So it might just not be suited to be moved there... You could also make a complete new Build Project and copy all build steps over but set this parameter different in both projects...

Comment: I think I will move them back to command line. It just confused me that TeamCity suggested a better approach without covering this common (I supposed) scenario.